# How do I know when custom form control is marked as pristine in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have several custom form control components in my Angular application, which implement `ControlValueAccessor` interface and it works great.

However, when `markAsPristine()` is called on parent form, or on my custom control directly I need to update it's state: my custom control is actually have internal control and I need to call `markAsPristine()` on it too.

**SO, how do I know when `markAsPristine()` is called on my control?**

The `ControlValueAccessor` interface has no members, related to this problem, which I can implement.

Comment: [**statusChanges**](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#statusChanges)?

Comment: According to the docs, the `statusChanges` observable emits when validation state changes, but I'm looking for dirty/pristine state changes.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I read so fast that I didn't understand what you really wanted. Well, AFAIK you can't know when the `markAs-*` methods are being called.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know a way to access the `FormControl` instance maybe?

Comment: I've extracted this sub-question to another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44731894/get-access-to-formcontrol-from-the-custom-form-component-in-angular

Comment: There is another way to check if the form is dirty or not. We can compare the object through which form is bind to.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

After thorough investigation I've found out that this functionality is not specifically provided by Angular. I've [posted an issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17736) in the official repository regarding this and it's gained feature request status. I hope it will be implemented in near future.

---

Until then, here's **two possible workarounds**:

## Monkey-patching the `markAsPristine()`

```typescript
@Component({
  selector: 'my-custom-form-component',
  templateUrl: './custom-form-component.html',
  providers: [{
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: MyCustomFormComponent,
    multi: true
  }]
})
export class MyCustomFormComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, OnInit {

  private control: AbstractControl;


  ngOnInit() {
    const origFunc = this.control.markAsPristine;
    this.control.markAsPristine = function() {
      origFunc.apply(this, arguments);
      console.log('Marked as pristine!');
    }
  }

}
```

## Watching for changes with `ngDoCheck`

Be advised, that this solution could be less performant, but it gives you better flexibility, because you can monitor when pristine state is changed. In the solution above, you will be notified only when `markAsPristine()` is called.

```typescript
@Component({
  selector: 'my-custom-form-component',
  templateUrl: './custom-form-component.html',
  providers: [{
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: MyCustomFormComponent,
    multi: true
  }]
})
export class MyCustomFormComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, DoCheck {

  private control: AbstractControl;

  private pristine = true;


  ngDoCheck(): void {
    if (this.pristine !== this.control.pristine) {
      this.pristine = this.control.pristine;
      if (this.pristine) {
        console.log('Marked as pristine!');
      }
    }
  }

}
```

---

And if you need to access the `FormControl` instance from your component, please see this question: [Get access to FormControl from the custom form component in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44731894/1056679).

Comment: How is `control` getting initialized?

Comment: @TravisP   constructor(@Optional() @Self() public ngControl: NgControl) {
    if (this.ngControl) {
      this.ngControl.valueAccessor = this;
    }
  }

Comment: Why is const self = this; unused?

Answer (score 1):

My workaround is inspired by Slava's post and [Get access to FormControl from the custom form component in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44731894/1056679), and mixing template forms (ngModel) and reactive forms together.
The checkbox control inside the component reflects dirty/pristine state and reports its state back outside to form group. So I can apply styles to checkbox input (`<label>`) control based on classes ng-dirty, ng-valid etc.
I have not implemented markAsTouched, markAsUntouched as it can be done in similar way.
Working demo on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-customcontrol-maketdirty?file=src/app/custom-checkbox-control/custom-checkbox-control.component.ts)

The example component code is:

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, Input, OnInit, Optional, Self, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
import { ControlValueAccessor, NgControl, NgModel } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: "app-custom-checkbox-control",
  template: '<input id="checkBoxInput"\
  #checkBoxNgModel="ngModel"\
  type="checkbox"\
  name="chkbxname"\
  [ngModel]="isChecked"\
  (ngModelChange)="checkboxChange($event)"\
>\
<label for="checkBoxInput">\
{{description}}\
</label>\
<div>checkbox dirty state: {{checkBoxNgModel.dirty}}</div>\
<div>checkbox pristine state: {{checkBoxNgModel.pristine}}</div>',
  styleUrls: ["./custom-checkbox-control.component.css"]
})
export class CustomCheckboxControlComponent
  implements OnInit, AfterViewInit,  ControlValueAccessor {
  disabled: boolean = false;
  isChecked: boolean = false;
 
  @Input() description: string;
  @ViewChild('checkBoxNgModel') checkBoxChild: NgModel;

  constructor(@Optional() @Self() public ngControl: NgControl) {
    if (this.ngControl != null) {
      this.ngControl.valueAccessor = this;
    }
  }

  checkboxChange(chk: boolean) {
    console.log("in checkbox component: Checkbox changing value to: ", chk);
    this.isChecked = chk;
    this.onChange(chk);

  }
  ngOnInit() {}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    debugger
    this.checkBoxChild.control.setValidators(this.ngControl.control.validator);

    const origFuncDirty = this.ngControl.control.markAsDirty;
    this.ngControl.control.markAsDirty = () => {
      origFuncDirty.apply(this.ngControl.control, arguments);
      this.checkBoxChild.control.markAsDirty();
      console.log('in checkbox component: Checkbox marked as dirty!');
    }

    const origFuncPristine = this.ngControl.control.markAsPristine;
    this.ngControl.control.markAsPristine = () => {
      origFuncPristine.apply(this.ngControl.control, arguments);
      this.checkBoxChild.control.markAsPristine();
      console.log('in checkbox component: Checkbox marked as pristine!');
    }

  }


  //ControlValueAccessor implementations

  writeValue(check: boolean): void {
    this.isChecked = check;
  }

  onChange = (val: any) => {};

  onTouched = () => {};

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    this.disabled = isDisabled;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion, based upon Slava's answer, is to replace the `markAsDirty`, `markAsPristine`, and `_updatePristine` methods in the `FormGroup` class:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  const markAsDirty = this.formGroup.markAsDirty;
  this.formGroup.markAsDirty = (opts) => {
    markAsDirty.apply(this.formGroup, opts);
    console.log('>>>>> markAsDirty');
  };
  const markAsPristine = this.formGroup.markAsPristine;
  this.formGroup.markAsPristine = (opts) => {
    markAsPristine.apply(this.formGroup, opts);
    console.log('>>>>> markAsPristine');
  };
  const updatePristine = this.formGroup['_updatePristine'];
  this.formGroup['_updatePristine'] = (opts) => {
    updatePristine.apply(this.formGroup, opts);
    console.log('>>>>> updatePristine');
  };
}
```

I'm emitting events in the `console.log` locations, but other approaches would work, of course.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to check if the form is dirty or not. We can compare the object through which form is bind to.Below function can be used for object properties comparison

```
isEquivalent(a, b) {
// Create arrays of property names
var aProps = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(a);
var bProps = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(b);

// If number of properties is different,
// objects are not equivalent
if (aProps.length != bProps.length) {
    return false;
}

for (var i = 0; i < aProps.length; i++) {
    var propName = aProps[i];

    // If values of same property are not equal,
    // objects are not equivalent
    if (a[propName] !== b[propName]) {
        return false;
    }
}

// If we made it this far, objects
// are considered equivalent
return true;
```

}

if you want to check this use below stackblitz link.
I have tested it  and is working well.
[Stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/angular/jralqademxp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhero-form%2Fhero-form.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem and I was able to solve it without having to build a custom Angular component.

In my use case, I needed to know the "dirty" state when navigating away from an edited page. The edited page consists of a Parent component with multiple child components.

I figured that I could determine its "dirty" state by creating a `public get isDirty(): boolean`  property and accessing it using Angular's `router` and `guard` when navigating away.

The "isDirty()" property performs a "dirtyCheck()" that peeks at the child components "dirty" state and returns a true/false.

When added to a guard & navigating away we're able to access the "dirty" state of the edited page.

```
    export class ParentComponent, IDirtyComponent {
      formGroup: FormGroup;
    
      @ViewChild('childComponent1') childComponent1: ChildComponent1;
      @ViewChild('childComponent2') childComponent2: ChildComponent2;
      @ViewChild('childComponent3') childComponent3: ChildComponent3;
    
      public get isDirty(): boolean {
        return this.dirtyCheck();
      }
    
      constructor(private readonly fb: FormBuilder) {
    
        this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
          company: [null],
          website: [null],
        });
    
    
      }
    
      public dirtyCheck(): boolean {
    
        if (this.formGroup.formGroup.dirty
            || this.childComponent1.formGroup.dirty
            || this.childComponent2.formGroup.dirty
            || this.childComponent3.formGroup.dirty) {
            return true;
          }
    
        return false;
      }
    
    }
    
    export class ChildComponent1 {
      formGroup: FormGroup;
    
      constructor(private readonly fb: FormBuilder) {
    
        this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
          name: [null],
          title: [null],
          website: [null],
        });
    
        this.loadData();
      }
    
      public loadData(): void {
    
        this.formGroup.get('name').setValue('John Doe');
        this.formGroup.get('title').setValue('CEO');
        this.formGroup.get('website').setValue('https://abc123.com');
    
        this.formGroup.markAsPristine();
    
      }
    }
    
    

    export interface IDirtyComponent {
      isDirty: boolean;
      dirtyCheck(): boolean;
    }
    
    
    @Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
    export class DirtyCheckGuard implements CanDeactivate<IDirtyComponent> {
      constructor(private modalSvc: FakeModalSvc) { }
    
      canDeactivate(component: IDirtyComponent) {
        if (component.isDirty === false) {
          // continue editing
          return true;
        }
    
        this.modalSvc.showIndicator();
    
        return this.modalSvc.continueEditing$.pipe(
          switchMap(continueEditing => {
    
            // leave page
            if (continueEditing === false) {
              return of(true);
            }
    
            // continue editing
            return of(false);
          }),
          take(1)
        );
    
      }
    }

const routes: Routes =
  [
    {
        path: "create",
        component: ParentComponent,
        canDeactivate: [DirtyCheckGuard],
        data: {
          title: "Create Company",
          breadcrumb: {
            label: "Create Company",
            disable: false
          }
        }
    }
  ];
```