# Angular custom material control does not show error when form control is touched programmatically

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-reactive-forms, controlvalueaccessor

I've created custom angular material control with ControlValueAccessor implemented. When submitting form, if it's invalid, I touch all the controls to make them show validation errors. For some reason my custom control gets highlighted, but does not show error texts. Here's a test project.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a2rrbx

I've actually found the solution already - implementing DoCheck and checking for touched state there and then emitting stateChanges. But I wonder if there's a better solution, not involving DoCheck, as it can turn out to be expensive.
The solution is described here: [How do I know when custom form control is marked as pristine in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44730711/how-do-i-know-when-custom-form-control-is-marked-as-pristine-in-angular). I'd like to avoid monkey-patching too.

I also can't uderstand why this is happening - the control is highlighted, so it sees the touch state, this is very confusing.

Thanks!