# ControlValueAccessor and touched

Tags: angular, typescript, controlvalueaccessor

I have implemented a date picker using three drop downs for date, month and year. The date picker is a component that implements ControlValueAccessor and is working great. However, I would like the control to expose touched when any of the three drop downs are touched.

There are lots of questions about related issues regarding touched, but not this specific issue which seems odd to me since it's something you would want to do by default!

How do I expose a touched state of my component? Additionally, how about pristine, dirty etc.?

Comment: Any chance you're using Material?

Comment: Nope, not using Matieral.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44730711/how-do-i-know-when-custom-form-control-is-marked-as-pristine-in-angular/44732590#44732590 ?. mask as touched must be easy, its only call to the function onTouched() you declare in your component when you change the dropdown.

Comment: I'm calliing `onTouched()` but it's not having any affect on the control's touched state.

Answer (score 2):

Only for touched: If your component extends of ControlValueAntecesor you have some like

```
//declare two functions onChange and onTouched
onChange;
onTouched;
//register onChange and onTouched
registerOnChange( fn : any ) : void {
    this.onChange = fn;
}

registerOnTouched( fn : any ) : void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
}
```

The only thing you need is, when you change one dropdown call to the function

```
this.onTouched()
```

Comment: I'm calliing `onTouched()` but it's not having any affect on the control's touched state.

Comment: I modified an old stackblitz of a customFormControl (it's more complex, but sirve the idea) to show how. When click the customControl, mask as touched. In a external button mark as untouched. see in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n9baag?file=src/app/app.component.html