# Angular ControlValueAccessor and markAsTouched

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-forms

I'm using angular 9 with Angular Material and I have a custom control by implementing the ControlValueAccessor interface. Everything is working fine.

In all my submit buttons when the form is not valid, I call formGroup.markAllAsTouched because all the angular material fields become in red. In this way the user can better understand which controls are not valid.

I need to implement the same behavior with my custom control. How to do that?

I've created a stackblitz project in order to better understand the situation [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sh8esy)

Comment: Your control doesn't mark as touched? Did you implement registerOnTouched in your control? Can you share your code?

Comment: I'm preparing a stackblitz example. I'll back to you soon

Comment: Here the example -> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sh8esy

Comment: First at all, I don't know why you are wrapping a mat-select in another ControlValueAccesor component, you can just share the userTypeCustomControl to the custom control and use it in the mat-select. You have a problem with classes and form control references

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Another chance is to use the following approach

Custom control code

```
@Component({
  selector: 'cvl-advertising-type',
  templateUrl: './advertising-type.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./advertising-type.component.scss'],
})
export class AdvertisingTypeComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {
  advertisingTypes: ReadonlyArray<LookupModel>;

  onChange = (value: number) => {
  };
  onTouched = () => {
  };

  constructor(private lookupService: LookupService,
              @Self() public controlDir: NgControl) {
    controlDir.valueAccessor = this;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.advertisingTypes = this.lookupService.advertisingTypes;
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: (value: number) => void): void {
    this.controlDir.control.valueChanges.subscribe(fn);
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  writeValue(value: number): void {
    this.controlDir.control.setValue(value);
    this.onChange(value);
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    if (isDisabled) {
      this.controlDir.control.disable();
    } else {
      this.controlDir.control.enable();
    }
  }
}
```

and parent html form

```
<cvl-advertising-type [formControl]="form.controls.advertisingType"></cvl-advertising-type>
```

I've found this solution after viewing this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CD_t3m2WMM8&index=15&list=PLAw7NFdKKYpGUpg7JJ8-PJNMdlrOnmZtN)

Last but not least problem is that I'm not understanding how to test it with a shallow test because I've the following error

```
Error: NodeInjector: NOT_FOUND [NgControl]
```

Comment: In order to test it properly you can either use wrapper component or add `@Optional` decorator for `NgControl`

Answer (score 13):

There is [no built-in functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44730711/how-do-i-know-when-custom-form-control-is-marked-as-pristine-in-angular) for propagating `touched` status to inner FormControl of custom control.

Your simple option would be checking status in `ngDoCheck` and once custom control becomes touched update status for inner `FormControl`:

```
ngDoCheck() {
  if (this.formControl.touched) {
    return;
  }
  if (this.controlDir.control.touched) {
    this.formControl.markAsTouched();
  }
}
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ptb82y?file=src/app/my-custom-control.component.ts)**

Personally, I don't like such kind of implementations with `ControlValueAccessor`.
I would rather use the same FormControl. This can be done by adding `viewProviders` with `ControlValueAccessor` provider to your custom control:

**custom-control.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-custom-control',
  template: `
    <mat-form-field id="userType">
      <mat-label>My Custom Component</mat-label>
      <mat-select [formControlName]="controlName" (blur)="onTouched()">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let current of userTypes" [value]="current.id">{{current.name}}</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>

  `,
   viewProviders: [{
    provide: ControlContainer,
    useFactory: (container: ControlContainer) => container,
    deps: [[new SkipSelf(), ControlContainer]],
 }]
})
export class MyCustomControl {
  @Input() controlName: string;

  userTypes: LookupModel[] = [
      new LookupModel(1, 'first'),
      new LookupModel(2, 'second')
  ];
}
```

**parent html**

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <my-custom-control controlName="userTypeCustomControl"></my-custom-control>
```

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qcoowv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

Comment: Is there a problem with the ControlValueAccessor pattern, because of which you opt for the second solution, or is it just a personal preference?